# Suppose $x_n < 0$ for all $n$. If $\lim(x_n) = 0$, prove that $\lim(1/x_n) = −∞$.

Tags: real-analysis

How do you go by proving this one . any hint ?

I have no idea where to start with this one

Comment: This really just comes directly from the definitions.  A good way to start problems like this is to write what you have, then write what you want.  Using the $\epsilon$-$N$ definition of a limit of a sequence, write down what $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n = 0$ means.  Then write down what $\lim_{n \to \infty} 1/x_n = \infty$ means.  Can you see any way to connect them?

Comment: so for this i see that |1/(Xn)|>1/ϵ and this means that it diverges.since ϵ>0 therefore 1/Xn is not in R.and all the terms are negative then the sequence diverge to −∞. @AntonioVargas

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$|x_n| < \epsilon \Rightarrow |\frac{1}{x_n}| > \frac{1}{\epsilon}$,
for all $\epsilon>0$

and use the definition of limit when this tends to infity.

Answer (score 0):

Let $1/x_n$ be lower bounded by some number $m\in \mathbb{R}$. Then, $l:=\inf_{n}1/x_n$ exists. Now, $x_n\to 0$ as $n\to \infty\implies,\ \forall \epsilon>0, \exists N, $ such that $\forall n\ge N,\ |x_n|\le \epsilon\implies |1/x_n|\ge 1/\epsilon$ That means $|l|\ge 1/\epsilon,\ \forall \epsilon>0$ which leads to a contradiction that $l\in \mathbb{R}$. Thus the sequence $1/x_n$ diverges, and since all the terms are negative it diverges to $-\infty$.